# Creating a Service with automator, caffeinate

Tags: bash, terminal, sleep, automator

First of all, sorry for my english, not a native speaker.
Since I'm a bit fed up opening Termninal and `^C` I want to create a shortcut for activating `caffeinate -d` on my Mac OS X 10.11
I've been trying a simple Automator Service but with my noob skills it doesn't work.

This is the settings:
I chose Service as type of document

Library->Utilities->Run Shell Script
Service receives: `no input`
in: `any application`
Shell: `/bin/bash`
Pass input: `to stdin`

```
CAFFEINATECHECK=`ps | grep caffeinate | cut -d ' ' -f7,8`
if [ $CAFFEINATECHECK == 'caffeinate -d' ]; then
killall caffeinate
else
caffeinate -d
fi
```

Problem is that such a short scrip keeps running with no response and I have to stop it after a minute
I hope someone could give me any tips necessary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution in [a duplicate on Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/383402)

In short, just replacing mine code with a more elegant command lines:

```
if [[ $(pgrep caffeinate) == "" ]]; then
    caffeinate -d &
else
    pkill caffeinate
fi
```

The only change I made inside user3439894's solution was to remove the '&' (usually useful at the end of a command line to run it in background) because apparently Automator doesn't work well with it *(shame I can't remember where I read/heard that..!)* .

After saving the Service I just had to

1. Open System Preferences Keyboard->Shortcuts->Services
2. Bind my shortcut with my saved workflow found under ▼General in the right pannel

This way a cog gear wheel ⚙ appears on the menubar when caffeinate shortcut is activated and spins till I deactive it .

Comment: I experienced a working bashscript not working inside Automator environment before (even if the syntax was clear and working line by line inside terminal). I still wonder what was that didn't let my code works smoothly afterall.